# What is the logic for the abbreviation in wc command?

Tags: shell

Some info in  `man wc`.

```
wc - print newline, word, and byte counts for each file.
  -c, --bytes
          print the byte counts

   -m, --chars
          print the character counts
```

Maybe it is better to use `-b`  indicating `byte` and `-c` indicating `character`.Why the author use `-c`  indicating `byte` and `-m` indicating `character` ?What is the logic for this abbreviation?

Answer (score 3):

From POSIX (https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/wc.html#tag_20_154)

> The -c option stands for "character" count, even though it counts bytes. This stems from the sometimes erroneous historical view that bytes and characters are the same size. Due to international requirements, the -m option (reminiscent of "multi-byte") was added to obtain actual character counts.